# Implementation of Vaadin `SQLGenerator` interface for H2 Database

Tags: vaadin, h2, vaadin7

The [`SQLGenerator`](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/data/util/sqlcontainer/query/generator/SQLGenerator.html) interface is a key piece to using [`SQLContainer`](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/data/util/sqlcontainer/SQLContainer.html) in a [Vaadin](http://www.Vaadin.com/) 7 app. (See [Book of Vaadin](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/sqlcontainer/sqlcontainer-architecture.html) for info)

Regarding implementations, the doc says:

> By default there are implementations for HSQLDB, MySQL, PostgreSQL, MSSQL and Oracle syntaxes

How about an implementation for the [H2 Database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H2_(DBMS))?

So far the [`DefaultSQLGenerator`](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/data/util/sqlcontainer/query/generator/DefaultSQLGenerator.html) implementation for [`SqlContainer`](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/data/util/sqlcontainer/query/generator/SQLGenerator.html) seems to be working with H2 Database. But I've just begun such usage.

Comment: I use H2 with JPA and the [JPAContainer](https://vaadin.com/directory#!addon/vaadin-jpacontainer). Works perfectly. Is that add-on an option for you?

Comment: No, thanks, I'm not interested in JPA.